# C# SDK Smartsheet Post w/ API

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

Morning all,

Using the c# sdk to write a program to post/update smartsheet with information from a database. I am in need of an explanation on how to post to both a checkbox and contact list field in smartsheet.

ie - checkbox shows as boolean value? however when i send a TRUE, FALSE, true, false, etc. values it is not the proper value. What exactly is needed to post and check a box or not?

as for contact list -

> "contactOptions": [
>                   {
>                       "name": "ed eddy",
>                       "email": "e.eddy@mail.com"
>                   }

is an example of value in there (json) do the values sent in order to update this field have to be in json format? what is needed to add new contacts, or select one of the existing contacts? there is NO documentation or explanation in the api2.0 documentation - and hoping i get a response better than one saying to reference api docs because it is not there.

--last attempt at using sdk before backend coding items since direct contact with smartsheet is unresponsive and clearly frowned upon >.>

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `value` of a checkbox column to `true` should check the box. You want to be sure you're setting the `value` and not the `displayValue`.

Will you post your code so that we can see where the disconnect is?

As for updating the `contactOptions` of a `CONTACT_LIST` column it states in the [documentation](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#update-column) that if your setting `contactOptions` that you must also set the `type` to `CONTACT_LIST`. What isn't clear is that it's talking about the body of the same request for setting `contactOptions`.

For example, hitting the API directly, you would use a request body like this

```
{
  "contactOptions":[
       {
            "name": "Susan",
            "email": "susan@example.com"
        }

    ],
    "type": "CONTACT_LIST"
}
```

With the C# SDK, you can be a little more direct, since you're dealing with a column object that
already has a type associated with it. That would look something like this:

```
 Contact newContact = new Contact();
 newContact.Name = "Susan";
 newContact.Email = "susan@example.com";

 column.ContactOptions = new Contact[] { newContact };
 ss.SheetResources.ColumnResources.UpdateColumn(sheetId, column);
```